# Run SSIS Package error in SQL Agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I run my SSIS package in SSDT and Success, but when I run the package using SQL Agent and get error.

The error message is below

```
copy_r_bp:Error: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY001] Out of memory while reading tuples.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

Can you help me ?
Or is there any solution to set schedule to execute the package ?

Thanks

Comment: What does it contains? What is the object using odbc connection? What is the size of data in odbc source? Please give us more infos on the package you have built.

Comment: I create connection between mssql and postgre using datasource32. I dont know why when I use datasource64 cannot connect.
the data size is only 200k record

Answer (score 0):

The error is straight-forward and tells you the exact problem: you are using up all the memory. Solution: instead of a large read, divide your read to smaller partitions and read everything using a cycle.

Comment: I have check my ram memory is still enough

Comment: It can be more complicated than that.  We had an occasion where a server, with lots of RAM, could not run a package developed and tested on an underpowered desktop.  In our cause parallel execution was to blame.  You need to work through all the differences between running as you, on a desktop in VS and running as agent on server.